# laravel retrieving request input returns null

Tags: php, mysql, string, laravel, null

Sorry if this question is asked elsewhere, but I've searched everywhere but couldn't find the answer. Well, I'm facing this problem on Laravel 5.0, when i try to get a variable from a request, Im getting **null** value on **Production Server** but im getting an **empty string** on the **Development Server**. The value is not present on the request, ie the field was empty when the form was submitted. eg.

```
// ProductController
public function store(Request $request) {
    // this field is actually empty in the submitted form
    $price = $request->price;
    // when it gets to the server this is how this value looks like :
    // $price in production server : null
    // $price in development server : ''
}
```

When i try to save the object to a database like

```
Product::save($request->only('name', 'price'));
```

I get this error(only on production server)

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'price'
>   cannot be null

NOTE that the price column has **'default 0'** on mysql table

Why is this happening?

**UPDATE:**

All this time i thought the request->input() method returned empty string('') if the field was not present. but just know i looked at the laravel source to see this :

```
public function input($key = null, $default = null)
{
    $input = $this->getInputSource()->all() + $this->query->all();

    return array_get($input, $key, $default);
}
```

here it returns null as the default value. then why am i getting empty string on development server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because mysql inserts the default value if you don't define anything. In this case Laravel sends a value, which is null. You should not use `Request::only`, instead use an array.

It's always good to be specific, it makes your code readable and consistent.

Comment: i've tried $request->only(), but it also returns null. is this by anyway related to different PHP versions?

Comment: I am saying that you should *not* use request->only

Comment: okay. but if i use an array like $data = ['name' => $request->name, 'price' => $request->price]; , $data['price'] is still null. this doesn't solve my problem either.

Answer (score 1):

> **Input Trimming & Normalization**
>
> By default, Laravel includes the `TrimStrings` and `ConvertEmptyStringsToNull` middleware in your application's global middleware stack. These middleware are listed in the stack by the `App\Http\Kernel` class. These middleware will automatically trim all incoming string fields on the request, as well as convert any empty string fields to `null`. This allows you to not have to worry about these normalization concerns in your routes and controllers.
>
> If you would like to disable this behavior, you may remove the two middleware from your application's middleware stack by removing them from the `$middleware` property of your `App\Http\Kernel` class.

From: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#input-trimming-and-normalization